# Get null when dumping index of boolean

Tags: php, arrays

When I execute this code I get NULL without any notice.

```
 $a = false;
 var_dump($a[5]);
```

Who can explain this?

Comment: there is nothing at index 5?

Comment: What is the need for a boolean variable to be dumped?

Comment: @Swift 5 is for example, you can try with 10 or 20 , whatever ...

Comment: @Thamilan I think it should get notice undefined index

Comment: @Vahe Galstyan I answered just the same way you had asked. It wasn't clear what you're asking actually. array index obviously wasn't defined.  Setting up proper question helps to understanding AND  often allows yourself find answer. If you stated your problem and referenced quote from language description, you  accidently could realize why it is happening.

Comment: Now I correcting my  answer why I didint get any notices?

Answer (score 2):

> Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the
>   same as accessing any other undefined variable: an `E_NOTICE-level`
>   error message will be issued, and the result will be `NULL`.
>
> **Array dereferencing a scalar value which is not a string silently**
>   **yields `NULL`, i.e. without issuing an error message.**

Please refer more details on this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: But I have not any notices, this is a reason why I am confused. (MY notifications are enabled).

Comment: Please read second point in my answer.....**which is not a string silently yields NULL, i.e. without issuing an error message**

Comment: what should be output $a=[]; var_dump($a[5]); ?

Comment: it will result `null` and also I tried your code it gives me notice Notice: Undefined offset: 5

Comment: Working example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f813dace30105c64c44a2f95791ccc3bed88ec38

Comment: Yes I know That when $a is array it give me notice but when $a is boolean it dosent give me any notice, this is my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136312/discussion-between-vahe-galstyan-and-naincy).

Comment: @VaheGalstyan can you see answer second point clearly.... made it bold...

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing Boolean variable in array form is not possible.
Index 5 you are accessing that is not available in `$a` that is the reason you are getting null in var_dump 
If you want to create array with Boolean value then it is possible
 
Check below code:

```
<?php
    $a = array(true, false, true, true, false, false);  
    var_dump($a[5]);
?>
```

Comment: No I know hove create array)). My question why I havent any notice ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two PHP configuration variables which control displaying error messages.

The first one is `display_errors`. If it's set to `On`, error messages will appear in the output.

The other one is `error_reporting`. It defines the severity level of the errors to display.

Both settings can be changed during runtime using `ini_set`.